# using rand method in ruby for computer vs player

Tags: ruby, random

I am trying to understand how to use rand to do this. if there were two players for example player a and player b and the computer had to be one and the human the other. How would i implement this?

Answer (score -2, accepted):

`[:computer, :player].shuffle.first` will give you on random who is first.

Comment: `sample` is more adequate

Comment: the tutorial i am following uses this

Comment: cpu = rand() > 0.5 ? 'X' : 'O'
user = @cpu == 'X' ? 'O' : 'X'